# Rxjava2 just method - how to run room insertion on another thread?

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I have a room persistant database insertion method which looks like this:

```
@Dao
public interface CountriesDao{

    @Insert(onConflict = REPLACE)
    List<Long> addCountries(List<CountryModel> countryModel);
}
```

I realize that this can't be run on the main thread. Here is how I define my database:

```
Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), MyDatabase.class).build();
```

I am trying to use rxjava2 so that I don't run on main thread. I have created the following method:

```
public void storeCountries(List<CountryModel> countriesList) {
        Observable.just(db.countriesDao().addCountries(countriesList))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new DefaultSubscriber<List<Long>>(){
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
                super.onSubscribe(d);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(@NonNull List<Long> longs) {
                super.onNext(longs);
                Timber.d("insert countries transaction complete");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
                super.onError(e);
                Timber.d("error storing countries in db"+e);
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                Timber.d("insert countries transaction complete");
            }
        });
    }
```

For me this is clearly now running on another thread. NOT the main thread but when I run this code i get the following error:

The full stack trace is below. Why is this happening ?

> Process: com.mobile.myapp.staging, PID: 12990
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on
>   the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period
>   of time.
>                                                                                      at
>   io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:111)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
>                                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on
>   the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period
>   of time.
>                                                                                      at
>   android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:138)
>                                                                                      at
>   android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.beginTransaction(RoomDatabase.java:185)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.mobile.myapp.data.room.dao.CountriesDao_Impl.addCountries(CountriesDao_Impl.java:165)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.mobile.myapp.data.repositories.CountryRepository.storeCountries(CountryRepository.java:42)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.mobile.myapp.UI.mvp.Presenters.SignUpPresenter.cacheCountries(SignUpPresenter.java:40)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.mobile.myapp.UI.mvp.Presenters.SignUpPresenter$CountriesSubscriber.onNext(SignUpPresenter.java:60)
>                                                                                      at
>   com.mobile.myapp.UI.mvp.Presenters.SignUpPresenter$CountriesSubscriber.onNext(SignUpPresenter.java:49)
>                                                                                      at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
>                                                                                      at
>   io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
>                                                                                      at
>   io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
>                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                      at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
>                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Not important but if you need to know what defaultSubscriber class looks like here it is:

**DefaultSubscriber.java**

```
public class DefaultSubscriber<T> implements Observer<T> {

Disposable disposable;

@Override
public void onSubscribe(@NonNull Disposable d) {
    disposable = d;
}

@Override
public void onNext(@NonNull T t) {

}

@Override
public void onError(@NonNull Throwable e) {
    Timber.e(e);
}

@Override
public void onComplete() {

}

public void unsubscribe(){
    if(disposable!=null && !disposable.isDisposed()){
        disposable.dispose();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is a common mistake: `just()` won't execute the "code" within its parenthesis as `just` takes a value, not a computation. You need `fromCallable`:

```
Observable.fromCallable(() -> db.countriesDao().addCountries(countriesList))
```

Comment: does a callable function automatically run on another thread without me having to call subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) ?

Comment: No, RxJava requires you to specify it just like before.

Comment: What about `Completable` mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/48307185/4308151

Comment: In Kotlin, you can do Observable.fromCallable{ dao.insert(thing) }

Answer (score 17):

Even better, you could use a `Completable`. Its description: *Represents a computation without any value but **only indication for completion** or **exception**.*

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> db.countriesDao().addCountries(list)).subscribe();
```

Comment: i really like this.  Completable represent Observable that emits no value, but only terminal events, either onError or onCompleted.  so it clean.

Comment: cleaner if you return void from the insert method!

Comment: Is this needs to be disposed?

Answer (score 12):

> Note: Room doesn't support database access on the main thread unless
>   you've called allowMainThreadQueries() on the builder because it might
>   lock the UI for a long period of time. Asynchronous queries - queries
>   that return instances of LiveData or Flowable are exempt from this
>   rule because they asynchronously run the query on a background thread
>   when needed.

So your code can be like this

```
Completable.fromAction(() -> db.countriesDao()
                .addCountries(list))
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe();
```

Comment: Perfect solution for me, not even need to return anything from callable

Answer (score 6):

From room room `2.1.0-alpha02`, you can use (`Completeable`, `Single`, `Maybe`) when insertion (
https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-rxjava-acb0cd4f3757)

**Example**

```
@Dao
interface UserDao{
     @Insert
     Completable insert(final User user); // currently, we must put final before user variable or you will get error when compile
}
```

Using

```
db.userDao().insert(user).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new Action() {
    @Override
    public void run() throws Exception {
        // success
    }
}, new Consumer < Throwable > () {
    @Override
    public void accept(Throwable throwable) throws Exception {
        // error
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the Single observable

```
        Single.create(new SingleOnSubscribe<List<Long>>() {
        @Override
        public void subscribe(SingleEmitter<List<Long>> emitter) throws Exception {
            try {
                List<Long> ids = db.countriesDao().addCountries(countriesList);
                emitter.onSuccess(ids);
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                emitter.onError(t);
            }
        }})
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .subscribeWith(new DisposableSingleObserver<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(List<Long> ids) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {

        }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have added both dependencies,
"implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxjava:3.0.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava3:rxandroid:3.0.0'"